# How to check if a row exist in the SQLite table with a condition

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite local database in my software. I want to check if a row exists based on the giver values of the row. for example : `"SELECT * FROM ftp WHERE Host LIKE '"+ host +"' AND Username LIKE '"+ username +"' "`

But I want to get boolean result so if finds the record do something and if not do something else. Hoe can I do this?

here is what I tired but it is always true, since it check if quesry runs and not if it returns data.

```
public void ftpTableCheck(String host, String port, String username, String password){
    try{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM ftp WHERE Host LIKE '"+ host +"' AND Username LIKE '"+ username +"' ";
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);

        if (pst.execute() == true){
            System.out.println("true");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any idea how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: You could use `select count(*) ...` which will return you a single row with the number of matching results...May you could try `select (count(*) > 0) as found ...` or something (ps- not tested ;))

Comment: I did a test with H2 (don't have SQLite installed) and `select (count(*) > 0) as found ...` worked for me and returned a boolean result

Comment: Well you're right it is working, even COUNT(*) works and give the right value in any SQL software. but in java, I must get the result of the query by ResultSet and this class seems doesnt have any method to show row count. That's what I am looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you can use something like `select count(*) ...` or `select (count(*) > 0) as found ...` as the base query.

When you call `executeQuery`, you will get a `ResultSet` in return, from this, you need to determine it's contents.

In your case, you are only expecting a single row result, so you can simply use `ResultSet#next` to move to the first row and then extract the column value from it...

```
public void ftpTableCheck(String host, String port, String username, String password) {
    try {
        String query = "SELECT (count(*) > 0) as found FROM ftp WHERE Host LIKE ? AND Username LIKE ?";
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, host);
        pst.setString(2, username);

        try (ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {
            // Only expecting a single result
            if (rs.next()) {
                boolean found = rs.getBoolean(1); // "found" column
                if (found) {
                    // You have rows
                } else {
                    // You have no rows
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Take a closer look at [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) and [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details

Comment: That makes a nice change. Glad it could help ;)

Answer (score 2):

The general method to do this is to fetch the results and check if it is not empty. For your question, it will be logical to count the returned rows.

As @MadProgrammer said, query like:

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ftp WHERE Host LIKE '"+ host +"' AND Username LIKE '"+ username +"' ";
```

Now you just have to get the count and check if it is 0 (NOT FOUND) or not (FOUND)

Comment: Thanks, it seems working in my SQL platform. But can you please say how to get the result to check if its 0 or more ?

Comment: @Dan I am not a java developer. But: Fetch your result as `ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(query)`;

Comment: Also look at this [tutorial](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/jdbc/jdbc0003)

Comment: This is dangerous. Vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: Right you are @Rafael