# How to check if record is present in sqlite in C

Tags: c, sqlite

I am just starting with sqlite, need some quick help. I have following code which is working. In the last query i.e `"Select * from company where id = 2"`. I just want to check if there exists a row having `id = 2`. That's it. But I am not able to do that. The call back method is common to all the queries so, can't modify it, and don't want to write a specific call back for last query.

Can I get just `0/1` or `False/True` for the last query?
What I have tried is to use, count rows but again with callback it prints the result but not 0/1.

```
 static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
 int i;
 for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
 }
 printf("\n");
 return 0;
}

int main()
{
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int rc;
   char *sql;

   /* Open database */
   rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
   if( rc ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      exit(0);
   }else{
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }

   sql = "CREATE TABLE COMPANY("  \
         "ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL," \
         "NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL," \
         "AGE            INT     NOT NULL," \
         "ADDRESS        CHAR(50)," \
         "SALARY         REAL );";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
   fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   }else{
      fprintf(stdout, "Table created successfully\n");
   }

      /* Create SQL statement */
   sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) "  \
         "VALUES (1, 'Paul', 32, 'California', 20000.00 ); " \
         "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) "  \
         "VALUES (2, 'Allen', 25, 'Texas', 15000.00 ); "     \
         "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)" \
         "VALUES (3, 'Teddy', 23, 'Norway', 20000.00 );" \
         "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)" \
         "VALUES (4, 'Mark', 25, 'Rich-Mond ', 65000.00 );";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   }else{
      fprintf(stdout, "Records created successfully\n");
   }

   sql = "Select * from COMPANY where id = 2";

   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   }else{
      fprintf(stdout, "Records created successfully\n");
   }

   sqlite3_close(db);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: And why can't you write a separate callback function for this?

Comment: But I want tor return 1 or 0 in rc indicating if row is present or not. Or how can I get callback function's return value?

Comment: The callback function's return value indicates whether an error occured, just like `sqlite3_exec`'s return value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a row exist in the SQLite table with a condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640246/how-to-check-if-a-row-exist-in-the-sqlite-table-with-a-condition)

Comment: No, its not. That question is specifically for Java. I am asking a simple way for C. I am yet to try the given answer and CL's comment. Please just don't downvote or mark duplicate without actually answering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can exec your query differently

```
    sql = "Select * from COMPANY where id = 2";
    struct sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
    int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL);
    if(result == SQLITE_OK)
    {
       if (sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
       {
          // record found
       }
       else
       {
          // no record found
       }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
```

Comment: I am getting core dumb with error of __pthread_mutex_lock: Assertion 'mutex->__data.__owner == 0' failed. Can we use something else like SELECT EXISTS ?

Comment: Not sure I'm getting you: take a look [at this man page](http://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/exists.php)

Comment: I changed the your answer a bit and now its working for me. Please accept the edit. I am accepting the answer. Thanks for your answer.